# World texturing techniques in FPS game

Tags: opengl, textures, rendering

Texturing for small objects (pickups and enimies) can easily be done UV-unwrapping the model, and use a texture of reasonable size to make the model look good. But how can texturing be done for the world? Covering a large building with one texture would require a huge texture (otherwise it will look blurry), and a lot of it will be repeated (brickwall textures, wallpapers ...), so that approach seems inefficient. Assigning different textures to different faces may be slow, since there cannot be a texture switch within the draw call.

I am targeting OpenGL 4 or later. I prefer good looking stuff rather than extremely high framerate: I aim for 30 fps, but perhaps with motion blur (which I guess requires four times that).

About tiling:

Tiling would work, but then there are some parts of the mesh which requires some other texture. And then I need to switch texture.

Comment: They usually make less visible objects less detailed, so they require a smaller image

Comment: @Bálint That is a good point, but does not apply since the player will be able to move close to the wall.

Comment: [This](http://i.imgur.com/J2kaVp2.jpg) is a screenshot i just took from csgo. And as you can see, it **is** blurred. I've never see a 3D game that doesn't have a blurred texture when you go near them or close-up (Except for those games with 4k textures, never try them). I say don't worry about it much.

Comment: You usually tile the texture multiple times so you can use a smaller texture for a larger polygon.

Comment: If you use very high res textures, you achieve the same what GTA V did.

Comment: I don't know if this is what you're aiming for or not, but you can pass 2 or more texture to the shader with `glActiveTexture()`  and pass a uniform to update the `sampler2D` so it use the right texture. After that you just have to somehow work at it so they render the right texture at the right place.